# Make Rails recognise my class inside a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a variable that stores the name of a class

```
my_class = "Homework"
```

This class has certain attributes which I would like to access

```
Homework.find_by
```

How can I make ruby see this string as an object?

e.g.

```
my_class.find_by
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `classify` and `constantize`

```
my_class.classify.constantize.find_by # something
```

> classify
>
> Create a class name from a plural table
>   name like Rails does for table names to models. Note that this returns
>   a string and not a Class (To convert to an actual class follow
>   classify with constantize).
>
> constantize
>
> Tries to find a constant with the name specified in the argument
>   string.

```
'Module'.constantize     # => Module 
'Test::Unit'.constantize # => Test::Unit
```

If you are sure about your input, you need only `constantize`

```
my_class.constantize.find_by # something
```

Comment: `2.3.1 :015 > 'Module'.constantize
NoMethodError: undefined method 'constantize' for "Module":String`

Comment: you need rails console, not irb.